# Getting a sorted, distinct list of integers in Prolog

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I'm trying to do something very simple while learning Prolog. However I'm confused why this works:

```
?- length( L, 3 ),
   maplist( member, L, [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]] ),
   sort( L, L ).
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
```

But this seemingly equivalent variation using clpfd doesn't:

```
?- use_module(library(clpfd)).

?- length( L, 3 ), L ins 1..3, sort( L, L ).
L = [_G5891, _G5894, _G5897],
_G5891 in 1..3,
_G5894 in 1..3,
_G5897 in 1..3.
```

This works:

```
?- length( L, 3 ), L ins 1..3, chain( L, #< ).
L = [1, 2, 3].
```

But this doesn't:

```
?- length( L, 3 ), L ins 1..3, chain( L, #=< ), all_different( L ).
L = [_G6519, _G6522, _G6525],
_G6519 in 1..3,
all_different([_G6519, _G6522, _G6525]),
_G6522#>=_G6519,
_G6522 in 1..3,
_G6525#>=_G6522,
_G6525 in 1..3.
```

Can anyone explain why the non-working examples don't give me the outcome I'm expecting?

As a side question, is there a more concise way to rewrite my `maplist` expression in the first example above?

Comment: It is not clear what your _goal_ is. What are you trying to do, really? And keep in mind that `sort(L, L)` only works because all your lists happen to be "sorted" already. Try passing `[1,3,2]` to `sort(L, L)`.

Answer (score 2):

#### CLP in Prolog

The system you are using (SWI-Prolog + library(clpfd)) is one example of the embedding of an integer finite-domain constraint solver into a Prolog system (some others are CHIP, ECLiPSe+fd/ic, B-Prolog, SICStus+clpfd).  Such an embedding is very natural in the sense that many Prolog concepts map directly to concepts in Constraint Programming, giving us Constraint Logic Programming (CLP).

However, there are number of features of plain Prolog that should be avoided when using it for CLP.  Among those are *cuts* (including the hidden ones in the if-then-else construct and the `\+/2` negation), but also *meta-logical* operations as in your case.  For our purposes, *meta-logical* means any primitive that treats variables as objects (rather than just as placeholders for values).  Examples of these are `var/1`, `==/2`, `@</2`, and indeed also `sort/2`.

Meta-logical primitives can already cause ugly effects in plain Prolog, e.g.

```
?-  X\==Y, X=3, Y=3, X==Y.
Yes
```

but Prolog programmers have learned to use them correctly and avoid such problems.  With CLP however, it is easier to fall into these traps because the execution control flow is much less obvious.

As to your examples, the first one works because `sort/2` sorts lists of integers, no problem there.  In the second case, `sort/2` sorts a list of domain variables, resulting in a list of domain variables in an arbitrary, system-defined order.  Once this is done, `sort/2` considers its job done.  If you later assign integer values to those ostensibly "sorted" variables, the sortedness of the list will not be checked again, and your program can now return unsorted integer lists as results.

The correct alternative is to use a sortedness check that involves only pure logical Prolog primitives and/or the constraint predicates defined by the CLP solver.  You have already done that by using the `chain/2` constraint in your third example.

#### Local Propagation and Search

In your last example you can observe the typical behaviour of a constraint solver based on *local propagation*:  The answer you get is correct, but not very satisfactory.  By analyzing the constraints more deeply, it is actually possible to infer that the only correct solution is `[1,2,3]`, but the solver doesn't do that because it could be computationally expensive. But look what happens if you add just a little bit of information:

```
?- L=[_,Y,_], L ins 1..3, chain(L, #=<), all_different(L), Y=2.
L = [1, 2, 3],
Y = 2
```

Ass soon as the solver knows that Y is 2, the problem becomes easy enough for the solver to solve completely.

A solution for the general case is to *systematically* break down the problem into simpler sub-problems, making sure you cover everything. In other words, you *add search*, and the Prolog way to do search is with a disjunction.  In the example, this could be a simple `member(Y,[1,2,3])`.  Typically, you want to do the same for *all* the domain variables in your problem, just to be on the safe side.  A CLP solver will give you a convenient primitive for this, e.g. in the case of `clpfd`

```
?- L=[_,_,_], L ins 1..3, chain(L, #=<), all_different(L), label(L).
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

This is a general structure for CLP programs: first constraint setup, then search.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in predicate `sort/2` effectively sorts a list based on the *term order* defined over all terms **including variables**. For this  reason this predicate cannot be considered to implement a concrete relation. Only in special cases like when the first argument is variable free (that is, `ground(L)` succeeds) and the term is acyclic (`acyclic_term(L)` succeeds), the built-in corresponds to the obvious relation.

Here is another such strange case `sort([X,1],[1,1])` which succeeds, unifying `X = 1`.